# SSIS Package for loop to expand list of AD group membership

Tags: ssis, active-directory, expansion, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

I am a fairly new user of SSIS tool and I love it! But I have a project that I don't know how to configure the tool. I have a list of about 300 domain groups in a MySQL table that I need to read each one via a loop and for each group query ActiveDirectory to get the list/enumeration of members. The results I would write to another table that would have the group name in first column and in second column the sAMAccountName. A row per each domain group member, not a single row with all the members but one row per account member of the group.

I am using KingswaySoft's SSIS Integration Toolkit for Directory Services connection manager to access AD information. - or if there is another mechanism it would also be great to hear what others are using!

I am good with the connection and writing to db tables, but the looping part and how to pass parameters and building the data rows to write is what has me scratching my head :\
-help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop through the group members within different groups, you would need to parameterize the **[ContainerPath]** property for the AD Source component. You can use the **Property Expressions Editor** in SSIS to parameterize this property and specify a variable which can be used in the Foreach Loop Container.

[image]

Once you have the **[ContainerPath]** property parameterized, you can put this data flow task (contains the AD Source component) into a **Foreach Loop Container** and provide group pathes to the variable you specified previously so that when you run the package the task will loop through all the groups and return members information for the corresponding group.

Thank you for choosing KingswaySoft as your integration solution. Hope this answers your question, please feel free to let us know if you have any further questions.

KingswaySoft Support

Answer (score 0):

You could user powershell to stage the data into a file and then load that with SSIS.  Powershell has a module of active directory cmdlets which can be used for this purpose.  Google "Remote Server Administration Tools" to search for where to download this.  This is the link for windows 10: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Here are some installation instructions > https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/

Once installed, follow these steps to set up the package:

1. Create a powershell script file (i.e. c:\temp\StageAdUsers.ps1)

   - add the following content:

:

```
$adserver = "mydomain.com"
$outputFile = "c:\temp\myad.txt"
if (test-path $outputFile)
{
    remove-item $outputFile
}


$groups = Get-ADGroup -server $adserver -filter * -Properties members
foreach($group in $groups)
{

    foreach($member in $group.members)
    {
        $user = get-aduser $member -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $newLine = "$($group.SamAccountName)`t$($user.SamAccountName)"
        add-content $outputFile  $newLine
    }
}
```

2. Add an execute process task.

   - Specify powershell as the executable (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe)
   - Add this as an argument: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\temp\StageAdUsers.ps1
3. Add a data flow task to load the contents of the flat file

In the script above, we use the Get_AdGroup cmdlet to fetch all groups.  This can be filtered down if that makes sense.  There is a cmdlet called Get-AdGroupMembers, but this has a size limitation, so we use "-properties members" as a workaround.
Finally, we stage the group name and user name in a line, separated by a tab (`t).  add-content will create the file if it does not exists and simply appends a new row.  The beginning of the script deletes the file if it exists.

m